# Alternative for \DeclareMathOperator

Tags: macros, math-operators, shorthands

I'm getting a little tired of defining all my mathematical operators with `\DeclareMathOperator`. Also it is rarely useful to have them as a macro. On the contrary it sometimes leads to macro name collision (e.g. `\span`). So I came up with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\catcode`\¡=\active
\def¡#1!{\operatorname{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \[e^{ix} = ¡cos! x + i¡sin! x\]
\end{document}
```

I'd like to get rid of the `!` at the end and maybe use `\ifmmode`, to allow `¡` in normal text. Is that possible? Are there other side effects of my definition I should be aware of?

Comment: `\newcommand{\op}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}`. However, I can't understand the point.

Comment: @egreg: Then I would have to write braces around the name. I don't want to write more than if I had used `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Comment: How can TeX know where to end the operator name?

Comment: It does know it for all the usual commands that start with `\ `.

Comment: Yes, but that's embedded in TeX's tokenization rules. I can't understand what's the point in not having a list of `\DeclareMathOperator` in the preamble.

Comment: It requires additional maintenance effort, that could be avoided.

Comment: If you've got certain operators you use over and over again, how about making a class which provides them for you.  Then  all you have to do is load the class anytime you want to use them.  As it is, you seem to be saving only three key strokes:  is it worth all that effort?

Comment: You're starting from a false premise. It's *good* to have a macro for constructs that are frequently used, such as the name of functions.

Comment: I will not argue with you, that using `\DeclareMathOperator` might be better. I just found that it can be annoying in certain cases. Especially when there are lots of operators which occur only a few times.

Comment: `\def¡#1 {\operatorname{#1}}` - use the space as a delimiter.

Comment: @Werner Did you try it with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are starting from a false premise: it's *good* to have macros for frequently used constructs and math operators such as “sine” and “log” are no exception.

If an operator appears only a few times, then what's wrong in using

```
\operatorname{foo}
```

for those few cases? If you don't want to type so much, then

```
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
```

would allow simply typing

```
\op{foo}
```

that requires just three keystrokes more than your proposed syntax.

It's quite difficult to have a safe routine for scanning a name in the same way TeX does for control sequences. The scanning of control sequence names is built-in, while you should do it character by character, storing them as you go until finding something that's not a letter.

There's another catch: your proposed character `¡` will definitely not work if the document is compiled under

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

because in that case it is not a single character, but two: its UTF-8 representation is `0xC2A1`. You could use `` ` ``, instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__canaaerus_name_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \canaaerus_bq_mathop:
 {
  % clear the container
  \tl_clear:N \l__canaaerus_name_tl
  % start the recursion
  \canaaerus_absorb:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \canaaerus_absorb:
 {
  \peek_catcode:NTF a
   {% if the next token is a letter absorb it
    \__canaaerus_absorb_next:n
   }
   {% otherwise produce the operator name
    \__canaaerus_deliver:
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__canaaerus_absorb_next:n #1
 {
  % add the next letter to the container
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__canaaerus_name_tl { #1 }
  % restart the recursion
  \canaaerus_absorb:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__canaaerus_deliver:
 {
  % produce the operator name
  \operatorname{\l__canaaerus_name_tl}
 }

% define the active back quote
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N `
\cs_gset_eq:NN ` \canaaerus_bq_mathop:
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff

% make the backquote math active
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode``=\string"8000 }

\begin{document}

$`cos(\alpha+\beta)-`sin x$

\end{document}
```

Highly inefficient, but working. Of course, syntax errors such as typing

```
`sinx
```

wouldn't be caught.

[image]

A different approach is to ease defining operators:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareMathOperators}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { canaaerus/mathop } { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { canaaerus/mathop }
 {
  unknown .code:n = \canaaerus_defop:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \canaaerus_defop:n #1
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { \l_keys_key_tl }
   {
    \msg_error:nnx { canaaerus/mathop } { exist } { \exp_not:c { \l_keys_key_tl } }
   }
   {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
     {
      \cs_new:cpx { \l_keys_key_tl } { \exp_not:N \operatorname { \l_keys_key_tl } }
     }
     {
      \cs_new:cpx { \l_keys_key_tl } { \exp_not:N \operatorname { #1 } }
     }
   }
 }
\msg_new:nnnn { canaaerus/mathop } { exist }
 {
  #1 already~defined
 }
 {
  The~command~#1 already~exists,~ignored
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \msg_error:nnn { nnx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareMathOperators{
  Tor,
  Hom,
  Span=span,
  %span, % if uncommented it would raise an error
}

\begin{document}
$\Tor\quad\Hom\quad\Span$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I use your code for defining a `\DeclareMathOperators` command as is, in a personal .sty or .cla file. I as k this question because it begins with `\NewDocumentCommand` – and a .sty or .cls file isn't really compiled.

Comment: @Bernard You can put the code in a `.sty` file; just change `\usepackage` into `\RequirePackage`. Put there all from `\RequirePackage` to `\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: Is it possible to get the character used (backtick or ¡) from a macro (e.g. an argument to a package)? I tried to place `\expandafter`s but it wouldn’t work...

Comment: @canaaerus `\expandafter` is not *abracadabra*; what precisely do you want to do?

Comment: `\abracadabra` doesn’t work either ^^. I have put the code into a _shortoperator.sty_ file and added a `kvoptions`-`StringOption` named `char`, so instead of the backtick I want to use `\shortoperator@char`. This has to be expanded in the definitions of course.

Comment: @canaaerus The ***only*** character that's safe for this purpose is the back quote. The inverted exclamation mark is definitely not safe, because with UTF-8 encoding it will explode.

Comment: It works for me with _XeLaTeX_. Also I could think of `?`, `@` and `"` that are rarely used in formulas.

Comment: @canaaerus Yes, with XeLaTeX it's possible. Regarding how to pass the character as an option to a package, it's better to ask a new question.

Comment: Just curious: does XeLaTeX see ¡ as a single character even though it is using UTF8 encoding? Or is its working the side-effect of another feature?

Comment: @cfr Yes, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX first transform UTF-8 multibyte combinations into single characters.