# Expand package option, to make contained character math-active

Tags: macros, expansion, package-options

In [an answer to another question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159375/15616), egreg posted code, which activates a character in math mode and gives it the function of `\operatorname`.

Now I want to put this into a package and set the character, that should be activated, in the package options. Just replacing the backtick with `\shortoperator@char`, it starts like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{shortoperator}[2014/02/09]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption[`]{char}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\RequirePackage{xparse,amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__shortoperator_name_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \shortoperator_bq_mathop:
 {
  % clear the container
  \tl_clear:N \l__shortoperator_name_tl
  % start the recursion
  \shortoperator_absorb:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \shortoperator_absorb:
 {
  \peek_catcode:NTF a
   {% if the next token is a letter absorb it
    \__shortoperator_absorb_next:n
   }
   {% otherwise produce the operator name
    \__shortoperator_deliver:
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__shortoperator_absorb_next:n #1
 {
  % add the next letter to the container
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__shortoperator_name_tl { #1 }
  % restart the recursion
  \shortoperator_absorb:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__shortoperator_deliver:
 {
  % produce the operator name
  \operatorname{\l__shortoperator_name_tl}
 }
```

and continuous with:

```
% define the active back quote
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \shortoperator@char
\cs_gset_eq:NN \shortoperator@char \shortoperator_bq_mathop:
\group_end:

\ExplSyntaxOff

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\shortoperator@char=\string"8000 }
```

where the option is used.

But of course that won’t work, because `\shortoperator@char` needs to be expanded. I tried to to use `\expandafter` to do that, but couldn’t get it to work. How can it be done?

An usage example (with *XeLaTeX*) would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[char=¡]{shortoperator}
\begin{document}
    \[e^{ix} = ¡cos x + i¡sin x\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: egreg also explained that ¡ is *two* characters in UTF8 so the example you use cannot work, can it? XeLaTeX assumes UTF8 input as standard.

Comment: @cfr: When I put `¡` in place of `\shortoperator@char` it does work. I guess for _XeLaTeX_ it’s just one character after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass `\shortoperator@char` in the context of a number.

Here's a workaround. At the start of the package write

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{shortoperator}[2014/02/09]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption[`]{char}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\edef\shortoperator@char{`\shortoperator@char}
```

This makes `\shortoperator@char` into something usable after `\mathcode`; then, the final part should be

```
% define the active back quote
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \^^A
\char_set_lccode:nn { `\^^A } { \shortoperator@char }
\tl_to_lowercase:n
 {
  \cs_gset_eq:NN ^^A \shortoperator_bq_mathop:
 }
\group_end:

\ExplSyntaxOff

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode\shortoperator@char=\string"8000 }
```

The `\lowercase` trick makes TeX “see” the (variable) character at the right spot.

You can make the whole package LaTeX3:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3,l3keys2e,amsmath}
\ProvidesExplPackage{shortoperator}{2014/02/09}
  {v. 0.1}{Shorthand for operator names}

\keys_define:nn { shortoperator }
 {
  char .tl_gset:N = \g_shortoperator_char_tl,
  char .initial:n = { ` }, % default is the back quote
 }

\ProcessKeysPackageOptions{ shortoperator }

% normalize the token list
\tl_gput_left:Nn \g_shortoperator_char_tl { ` }

\tl_new:N \l__shortoperator_name_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \shortoperator_bq_mathop:
 {
  % clear the container
  \tl_clear:N \l__shortoperator_name_tl
  % start the recursion
  \shortoperator_absorb:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \shortoperator_absorb:
 {
  \peek_catcode:NTF a
   {% if the next token is a letter absorb it
    \__shortoperator_absorb_next:n
   }
   {% otherwise produce the operator name
    \__shortoperator_deliver:
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__shortoperator_absorb_next:n #1
 {
  % add the next letter to the container
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__shortoperator_name_tl { #1 }
  % restart the recursion
  \shortoperator_absorb:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__shortoperator_deliver:
 {
  % produce the operator name
  \operatorname{\l__shortoperator_name_tl}
 }

% define the active back quote
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \^^A
\char_set_lccode:nn { `\^^A } { \g_shortoperator_char_tl }
\tl_to_lowercase:n 
 {
  \cs_gset_eq:NN ^^A \shortoperator_bq_mathop:
 }
\group_end:

% at begin document, make the character math active
\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \char_set_mathcode:nn { \g_shortoperator_char_tl }{ "8000 }
 }
```